# Library to draw graphics of UI components

Tags: c++, user-interface, graphics

I have made mostly generic UI framework that uses SDL2. All my core code is largely complete and I'm at point of adding different controls.

I'm trying to find some nice drawing library for C++ that will allow me to draw controls on screen little bit nicer, I have option that images can be used for controls also but that is not resolution independent and I can draw them also using SDLs simple rectangles and lines right now.

Abstraction of controls rendering allows for implementation of drawing library that can be used just for visual representation.

I would like to skip the part of making my own drawing library general requirements would be:

- Multi platform (win, linux, osx is a must)
- Not dependant on 100s of other libraries. (As low as possible if
  possible)
- Ability to draw shapes (rectangle, rounded rect, ellipse...)
- Drawing outlines of shapes would be nice
- Shadows extremely nice (but I'm sure i would have to do this, just wishful)
- Different types of gradients to fill shapes
- TTF support would be nice but not mandatory I use SDLs
- It should be compatible with SDL at least in a way that I can get
  back anything convertible to SDL_Surface or SDL_Texture
- Open Source and free

Those are the wishes now I'm turning to you to ask do you know what lib can match most of this points.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with Qt, it is portable, self-contained and very powerful application development framework. It coves all your requirements, and then some. In fact, with it, you can forget about SDL entirely.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware that Qt is great framework and I use it for some projects. But this time I made small framework my self that is functioning well for intended use I'm just looking at the way of making it more pretier.

Comment: Well, computer graphics is a complex thing and involves a lot of code base to support different graphics features. For example Cairo is only graphics but its sources are still a 40MB archive. SDL is small but it cannot really draw anything. AGG is small but it is very limited in terms of features, with Qt you have both low level graphics all the way to high level shapes, paths, animation and graphical effects such as shadows, blur and whatnot, and all that - hardware accelerated unlike AGG, whose latest release is almost 10 years old now...

Answer (score 0):

Could do a lot worse than [AGG](http://www.antigrain.com/).  May require some configuration of course, for your specific needs.  Not sure about shadows (you can do those yourself quite easily anyway).